# problema al realizar una consulta en laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

Realizo esta consulta:

```
public static function searchYear($year)
{
    return DB:: table('contract_works')
    ->select(DB::raw('Year(dateFailure) as dt'))
    ->where('dt',$year)
    ->orderBy('dt','asc')
    ->get();
}
```

pero me dice que el campo no existe, obteniendo este error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dt' in 'where clause' (SQL: select Year(dateFailure) as dt from `contract_works` where `dt` = 1970 order by `dt` asc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que *dt* es un alias y los alias no pueden ser referenciados en el WHERE.

Esto se debe a que el WHERE es ejecutado primero que el SELECT.

Puedes utilizar

```
    ->where('Year(dateFailure)',$year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza un subquery:

```
SELECT dt FROM 
(
SELECT Year(dateFailure) AS dt FROM contact_works
) AS table1 
WHERE dt = 'foo'
ORDER BY dt ASC
```